# Tricky Proof of the Coefficients of the Zero Function Polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, polynomials, proof-verification, proof-explanation

I am having difficulty understanding the *intuition behind the proof* for the following theorem:

> Suppose $a_0,a_1,\dots, a_m \in \mathbb F.$ If $$a_0 + a_1z^1+ \cdots + a_mz^m = 0$$ for every $z \in \mathbb F$, then $a_0 =a_1 =\dots = a_m = 0$

The proof I am referring to below is from Sheldon Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right.

[image]

*Question 1* : Doesn't the choice of $z$ only prove the theorem for $z \ge1$?

*Question 2* : Why should we let $z$ be represented in terms of the coefficients? Normally in a function, we wouldn't define the independent variable ($z$) in terms of the parameters(the coefficients) would we?

*Question 3* : How is $(|a_0|+ |a_1|+ \cdots|a_{m-1}|)z^{m-1} < |a_m z^m|$ for possible cases in which coefficients, in addition to $a_m$, do not equal to $0$?

*Side Yes/No Question*: Can this theorem be proven with induction by taking the derivative and showing the constant term to be zero on each step also?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Hint Q1: this is a proof by contradiction, so it's enough to find *one* $z$ for which $P(z) \ne 0$, which is precisely what the proof does.

Comment: Hint Q2: that is a choice, a tricky choice.

Comment: @dxiv Because the original statement is of the form $P \Longrightarrow Q $ by assuming $\lnot Q$ we prove $\lnot P$, will it be a contradiction as we will have $P \land \lnot P$ ?? I think my reasoning is wrong here however

Comment: The way it's phrased it actually proves the contrapositive, which is equivalent to the original implication. Lookup [proof by contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contrapositive). I called it [proof by contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction) in my previous comment since the two are closely related, to the point where it's essentially a simple matter of rephrasing between the two.

Comment: To the side question: Yes, but this requires you setting up the whole machinery of derivatives beforehand. A better proof along these lines would use finite differences instead of derivatives.