# Two questions about a proof that "if a polynomial is the zero function, all of its components are zero."

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

In *Linear Algebra Done Right*, Axler proves the following theorem:

> Suppose $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_m \in F$. If $a_0+a_1 z+⋯+a_mz^m=0$ for every $z \in F$, then  $a_0, \dots, a_m = 0$.

by contrapositive.

He starts his proof by letting $z$ (the input to the polynomial) equal

$$
\frac{|a_0| + |a_1| + \cdots +|a_{m-1}|}{|a_m|} + 1.
$$

He then goes on to show that $ |a_0 + a_1 z + \cdots +a_{m-1} z^{m-1}| < |a_m z^m| $ by stating two successive inequalities,

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
|a_0 + a_1 z + \cdots +a_{m-1} z^{m-1}| & \leq & (|a_0| + |a_1| + \cdots +|a_{m-1}|) z^{m-1} \\
& \lt & |a_m z^m|.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

While I understand why this proves the theorem, I don't understand:

1. Why he chose $z$ equal to the above fraction as opposed to an
   arbitrary element of $F$? Is its value being used by either of the
   above two inequalities? It doesn't seem to be on the surface.
2. Why it's guaranteed that $ (|a_0| + |a_1| + \cdots +|a_{m-1}|)
   z^{m-1} \lt |a_m z^m| $ given that some $ a_0, \dots, a_{m-1} $ may
   be non-zero.

*I know that [this previously unanswered question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016072/tricky-proof-of-the-coefficients-of-the-zero-function-polynomial) asks similar questions but I think/hope I've provided more specific questions regarding the proof.*

Comment: For the contrapositive, the "for all" on the $z$ becomes a "there exists". So in the proof you can just pick a specific $z$.

Comment: Thanks! I actually understood that part but didn't understand why he chose *this specific z* beyond that he wanted z to be greater than 0. The expression seemed complicated enough to have a more specific purpose than that.

Comment: Edit to my prior comment: "greater than $0$" should be "greater than $1$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of $z$ was chosen in order to make both inequalities true.  The next-to-last step,
$$
|a_0 + a_1 z + \cdots +a_{m-1} z^{m-1}| \leq (|a_0| + |a_1| + \cdots +|a_{m-1}|) z^{m-1},
$$
is true for any value of $z\ge 1$ (it requires $z^{m-1}$ to be at least as large as the lower powers of $z$).  However, the next,
$$
(|a_0| + |a_1| + \cdots +|a_{m-1}|) z^{m-1} \lt |a_m z^m|,
$$
may require $z$ to be larger.  Notice that it fails if $z = 1$ and $|a_0| + |a_1| + \cdots +|a_{m-1}| \ge |a_m|$.

How large does $z$ need to be?  Assuming $z\gt 0$, the desired inequality can be divided by $|a_m|z^{m-1}$ to get an equivalent statement:
$$
\frac{|a_0| + |a_1| + \cdots +|a_{m-1}|}{|a_m|} \lt z.
$$
To make sure that this is true, and also that $z\ge 1$ for the previous step, it will work to let
$$
z = \frac{|a_0| + |a_1| + \cdots +|a_{m-1}|}{|a_m|} + 1.
$$
(By the way, notice the absolute value in the denominator.  You omitted that in your question, but it is needed.)